# How to get filename in variable inside loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file, filenames

I want to loop through all .h files in the current directory and call a batch function for the corresponding .cpp file. Actually I had it working already, but when I tried to use local variables I get some strange output.

```
SETLOCAL

for /R  %%f in (*.h) do (
    SET header=%f%
    ECHO header=%header%
    SET source=%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.cpp
    ECHO source=%source%
)
```

I get this output:

```
SETLOCAL

C:\WorkingDirectory>(
SET header=
 ECHO header=
 SET source=C:\WorkingDirectory\SomeFile.cpp
 ECHO source=
)
header=
source=
```

Why is `%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.cpp` correctly expanded, but `ECHO %source%` prints nothing? How can I correctly `SET header=%f%`?

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: `%f%` should actually read `%%f`, or even better, `%%~f` to remove potential surrounding quotes... for reading `header` you need to use `!header!` instead of `%header%`; for this delayed expansion to work, add argument `EnableDelayedExpansion` to the `setlocal` command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The variable you are accessing is not accessed with `%f%` but `%%f`

2) As @npocmaka already mentioned as a comment `DelayedExpansion` is needed as in batch every block of closed parenthesis is parsed at once when using the usual `%`. To get rid of that problem, add `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to your script after `@echo off` and change `%header%` to `!header!`. The same goes for `%source%`, but not so for the loop variable `%%f`!

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for  %%f in (*.h) do (
    SET header=%%~ff
    ECHO header=!header!
    SET source=%%~df%%~pf%%~nf.cpp
    ECHO source=!source!
)
```

Comment: I allowed myself to add the working example. I use `%%~ff` to get the full path

Comment: Thats fine. Glad I could help!